# Is it normal for a cat to kick their own face?

Tags: cats

My cat keeps kicking her own face. Most of the time, she does it after play or when she gets in trouble. She seems to kick hard, and I'm scared she might hurt herself. After she's done though, she acts as if she did nothing at all. Is this normal for a cat to do?

She uses her back legs to kick herself and kicks her muzzle and where her eyes are. She doesn't seem to have any triggers for this behavior other than playing and when she gets in trouble, but she also does it randomly and we don't know why. She usually closes her eyes when kicking herself and her ears flatten.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your cat is doing? My first thought was scratching herself - which she’d typically do with her back leg - or grooming (perhaps a bit hectic, as self-soothing). Please give us more information to work with.

Comment: as your question is now it sounds like your cat gets overstimulated and stressed,but this is only one of the possible causes.please tell a bit more about the situations when she kick herself,what happens before-during and after she kicks herself?

Comment: Would you please answer the question of Stephie? What leg does the cat use (front or other)? What direction goes the kick (parallel - similar to cleaning, pad at the face, upside of paw at the face)? What area of the face is it aiming? You even can include a picture or video, if this is possible for you.

Comment: I found a lots of videos at youtube showing cats kicking their face with the hindlegs. "cat kicking own face" ... (but am no cat expert to explain it...)

Answer (score 2):

My cat kicks himself in the face in a similar manner to how you describe. I've noted he does it when he's all riled up and needing to play and "attack". If we already have been playing, it's a good sign he still has energy to burn. When he starts doing this, I take some time to keep playing with him to help release his energy.

If I don't have time to play with him, I give him a [kicker toy](https://www.thesprucepets.com/best-kicker-toys-for-cats-6754190), so he can redirect his kicks. I think cats do "bunny kicks" as an instinctual killing technique. So you can give your cat something to hold in her front paws and kick to simulate that experience.

I doubt your cat is hurting herself. If you do get concerned about the frequency or occasion at which your cat kicks herself, or she actually shows signs of pain or injury, I recommend taking a video or two of the action, and then showing your vet during your next visit.